# Installing a partition of Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I originally had a laptop with Windows 8, but I wiped it and installed Strictly Ubuntu. However, I am realizing that there are some tasks that are better suited towards Windows. I was looking to Dual boot and install Windows 8 on a small partition alongside my Ubuntu, however, I would rather not lose GRUB, and last time I dual booted, I seemed to have messed up the boot order in my BIOS. So do you ladies and Gentlemen have and advice to me on how to successfully complete this task? Perhaps a tutorial you know of. I have seen many that are suited towards installing Ubuntu after Windows is already present, but I was hoping for the inverse.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) to give you an idea about having both together, especially the boot repair part. But the quick and easy steps, taking into consideration you already have Ubuntu installed and want Windows 8 now (Which means there is no need to worry about UEFI, Secure Boot and other issues) would be:

1. With the LiveUSB of Ubuntu, use gparted to shrink the Ubuntu space in order to create empty space to install Windows. I am assuming Ubuntu took the whole drive. I recommend doing it this way since the Windows 7 and 8 partition tool in their installer has had several problems messing up the Ubuntu partition. After you have the space needed for Windows 8 you can keep on reading.
2. Install Windows 8 like you normally would. Select the empty space and all the steps that are shown in the installer.
3. Since you installed Windows AFTER Ubuntu, the boot part of Ubuntu will not work. To fix this, simply plug the LiveUSB of Ubuntu again, this time as I mentioned in the link above in the troubleshooting section, open a Terminal and type the following:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair   
   sudo apt-get update   
   sudo apt-get install boot-repair
   ```

   Now run `boot-repair`

   Boot Repair will mention that you have some GRUB error, just click on Apply so boot repair fixes everything. Now reboot and you should see Windows 8 and Ubuntu side by side on the same GRUB menu. I again mentioned gparted and doing the partition with the LiveUSB or LiveDVD because it is really fast, saves you some issues that could appear when using the partition manager of the Windows 7/8 installer and it is easier.

Comment: Wow, very in-depth. I appreciate it Luis, I will let you know how it works when I get a chance to try it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you wiped Windows & installed Ubuntu, you could have installed in either BIOS or UEFI. If BIOS then drive may be MBR(msdos) or gpt partitioned. If UEFI then you must install Windows in UEFI mode. IF BIOS and MBR you must install Windows in BIOS mode. But if Ubuntu is BIOS on a gpt drive you will have issues as Windows only installs to gpt drives with UEFI.

Comment: What oldfred mentions is also true. Good thing I posted the link about WIndows 8 then, but as oldfred mentioned, depending on how Ubuntu was installed (With UEFI or Legacy) you will need to install Windows using the same way. Thanks oldfred.

Comment: Alright, I'm about ready to set this up this coming weekend, however I had one last question: I backed up all of my files, and am going to wipe ubuntu 12.04 and install the new 14.04. (I think I messed up some drivers and such during my use of ubuntu 12 and want a fresh install) So I assume I will need a live USB of 14 correct?

Comment: You are correct. Download the 14.04 ISO image (32 or 64 depending on your taste and hardware) and burn it to the USB using the USB Disk Creator in 12.04. Then test to see if it boots first before doing anything this weekend.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot, will update if any problems arise, for now, thanks for all the help!